# Modifying JS code to remove DatePicker option

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a datepicker to a page I'm creating.  Since I don't know much at all about Javascript I'm modifying an example I've found at https://code-boxx.com/simple-datepicker-pure-javascript-css/.  I don't want any extra pages or files as I need the form I'm creating to be entirely self-contained.  I've condensed it down to this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Date Picker Example</title>
    <style>
      /* (A) POPUP */
      .picker-wrap {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: opacity 0.2s;
      }
      .picker-wrap.show {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
      }
      .picker-wrap .picker {
        margin: 50vh auto 0 auto;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }

      /* (B) CONTAINER */
      .picker {
        max-width: 300px;
        background: #444444;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      /* (C) MONTH + YEAR */
      .picker-m, .picker-y {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 5px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      /* (D) DAY */
      .picker-d table {
        color: #fff;
        border-collapse: separate;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
      .picker-d table td {
        width: 14.28%; /* 7 EQUAL COLUMNS */
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      /* HEADER CELLS */
      .picker-d-h td {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      /* BLANK DATES */
      .picker-d-b {
        background: #4e4e4e;
      }
      /* TODAY */
      .picker-d-td {
        background: #d84f4f;
      }
      /* PICKABLE DATES */
      .picker-d-d:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
      /* UNPICKABLE DATES */
      .picker-d-dd {
        color: #888;
        background: #4e4e4e;
      }
    </style>

    <!-- (A) LOAD DATE PICKER -->
    <!--<link href="dp-dark.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <link href="dp-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="datepicker.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- (B) THE HTML  -->
    <!-- (B1) INLINE DATE PICKER -->
    <input type="text" id="input-inline" placeholder="Inline" />
    <div id="pick-inline"></div>

    <!-- (B2) POPUP DATE PICKER -->
    <input type="text" id="input-pop" placeholder="Popup" />

    <!-- (C) ATTACH DATE PICKER ON LOAD -->
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        // (C1) INLINE DATE PICKER
        picker.attach({
          target: "input-inline",
          container: "pick-inline",
        });

        // (C2) POPUP DATE PICKER
        picker.attach({
          target: "input-pop",
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
  <script>
    var picker = {
      // (A) ATTACH DATEPICKER TO TARGET
      // target : datepicker will populate this field
      // container : datepicker will be generated in this container
      // startmon : start on Monday (default false)
      // disableday : array of days to disable, e.g. [2,7] to disable Tue and Sun
      attach: function (opt) {
        // (A1) CREATE NEW DATEPICKER
        var dp = document.createElement("div");
        dp.dataset.target = opt.target;
        dp.dataset.startmon = opt.startmon ? "1" : "0";
        dp.classList.add("picker");
        if (opt.disableday) {
          dp.dataset.disableday = JSON.stringify(opt.disableday);
        }

        // (A2) DEFAULT TO CURRENT MONTH + YEAR - NOTE: UTC+0!
        var today = new Date(),
          thisMonth = today.getUTCMonth(), // Note: Jan is 0
          thisYear = today.getUTCFullYear(),
          months = [
            "Jan",
            "Feb",
            "Mar",
            "Apr",
            "May",
            "Jun",
            "Jul",
            "Aug",
            "Sep",
            "Oct",
            "Nov",
            "Dec",
          ];

        // (A3) MONTH SELECT
        var select = document.createElement("select"),
          option = null;
        select.classList.add("picker-m");
        for (var mth in months) {
          option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = parseInt(mth) + 1;
          option.text = months[mth];
          select.appendChild(option);
        }
        select.selectedIndex = thisMonth;
        select.addEventListener("change", function () {
          picker.draw(this);
        });
        dp.appendChild(select);

        // (A4) YEAR SELECT
        var yRange = 10; // Year range to show, I.E. from thisYear-yRange to thisYear+yRange
        select = document.createElement("select");
        select.classList.add("picker-y");
        for (var y = thisYear - yRange; y < thisYear + yRange; y++) {
          option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = y;
          option.text = y;
          select.appendChild(option);
        }
        select.selectedIndex = yRange;
        select.addEventListener("change", function () {
          picker.draw(this);
        });
        dp.appendChild(select);

        // (A5) DAY SELECT
        var days = document.createElement("div");
        days.classList.add("picker-d");
        dp.appendChild(days);

        // (A6) ATTACH DATE PICKER TO TARGET CONTAINER + DRAW THE DATES
        picker.draw(select);

        // (A6-I) INLINE DATE PICKER
        if (opt.container) {
          document.getElementById(opt.container).appendChild(dp);
        }

        // (A6-P) POPUP DATE PICKER
        else {
          // (A6-P-1) MARK THIS AS A "POPUP"
          var uniqueID = 0;
          while (document.getElementById("picker-" + uniqueID) != null) {
            uniqueID = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 2)) + 1;
          }
          dp.dataset.popup = "1";
          dp.dataset.dpid = uniqueID;

          // (A6-P-2) CREATE WRAPPER
          var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
          wrapper.id = "picker-" + uniqueID;
          wrapper.classList.add("picker-wrap");
          wrapper.appendChild(dp);

          // (A6-P-3) ATTACH ONCLICK TO SHOW/HIDE DATEPICKER
          var target = document.getElementById(opt.target);
          target.dataset.dp = uniqueID;
          target.readOnly = true; // Prevent onscreen keyboar on mobile devices
          target.onfocus = function () {
            document
              .getElementById("picker-" + this.dataset.dp)
              .classList.add("show");
          };
          wrapper.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
            if (evt.target.classList.contains("picker-wrap")) {
              this.classList.remove("show");
            }
          });

          // (A6-P-4) ATTACH POPUP DATEPICKER TO BODY
          document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
        }
      },

      // (B) DRAW THE DAYS IN MONTH
      // el : HTML reference to either year or month selector
      draw: function (el) {
        // (B1) GET DATE PICKER COMPONENTS
        var parent = el.parentElement,
          year = parent.getElementsByClassName("picker-y")[0].value,
          month = parent.getElementsByClassName("picker-m")[0].value,
          days = parent.getElementsByClassName("picker-d")[0];

        // (B2) DATE RANGE CALCULATION - NOTE: UTC+0!
        var daysInMonth = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, 0)).getUTCDate(),
          startDay = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, 1)).getUTCDay(), // Note: Sun = 0
          endDay = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, daysInMonth)).getUTCDay(),
          startDay = startDay == 0 ? 7 : startDay,
          endDay = endDay == 0 ? 7 : endDay;

        // (B3) GENERATE DATE SQUARES (IN ARRAY FIRST)
        var squares = [],
          disableday = null;
        if (parent.dataset.disableday) {
          disableday = JSON.parse(parent.dataset.disableday);
        }

        // (B4) EMPTY SQUARES BEFORE FIRST DAY OF MONTH
        if (parent.dataset.startmon == "1" && startDay != 1) {
          for (var i = 1; i < startDay; i++) {
            squares.push("B");
          }
        }
        if (parent.dataset.startmon == "0" && startDay != 7) {
          for (var i = 0; i < startDay; i++) {
            squares.push("B");
          }
        }

        // (B5) DAYS OF MONTH
        // (B5-1) ALL DAYS ENABLED, JUST ADD
        if (disableday == null) {
          for (var i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
            squares.push([i, false]);
          }
        }

        // (B5-2) SOME DAYS DISABLED
        else {
          var thisday = startDay;
          for (var i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
            // CHECK IF DAY IS DISABLED
            var disabled = disableday.includes(thisday);
            // DAY OF MONTH, DISABLED
            squares.push([i, disabled]);
            // NEXT DAY
            thisday++;
            if (thisday == 8) {
              thisday = 1;
            }
          }
        }

        // (B6) EMPTY SQUARES AFTER LAST DAY OF MONTH
        if (parent.dataset.startmon == "1" && endDay != 7) {
          for (var i = endDay; i < 7; i++) {
            squares.push("B");
          }
        }
        if (parent.dataset.startmon == "0" && endDay != 6) {
          for (var i = endDay; i < (endDay == 7 ? 13 : 6); i++) {
            squares.push("B");
          }
        }

        // (B7) DRAW HTML
        var daynames = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat"];
        if (parent.dataset.startmon == "1") {
          daynames.push("Sun");
        } else {
          daynames.unshift("Sun");
        }

        // (B7-1) HTML DATE HEADER
        var table = document.createElement("table"),
          row = table.insertRow(),
          cell = null;
        row.classList.add("picker-d-h");
        for (let d of daynames) {
          cell = row.insertCell();
          cell.innerHTML = d;
        }

        // (B7-2) HTML DATE CELLS
        var total = squares.length,
          row = table.insertRow(),
          today = new Date(),
          todayDate = null;
        if (
          today.getUTCMonth() + 1 == month &&
          today.getUTCFullYear() == year
        ) {
          todayDate = today.getUTCDate();
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
          if (i != total && i % 7 == 0) {
            row = table.insertRow();
          }
          cell = row.insertCell();
          if (squares[i] == "B") {
            cell.classList.add("picker-d-b");
          } else {
            cell.innerHTML = squares[i][0];
            // NOT ALLOWED TO CHOOSE THIS DAY
            if (squares[i][1]) {
              cell.classList.add("picker-d-dd");
            }
            // ALLOWED TO CHOOSE THIS DAY
            else {
              if (i == todayDate) {
                cell.classList.add("picker-d-td");
              }
              cell.classList.add("picker-d-d");
              cell.addEventListener("click", function () {
                picker.pick(this);
              });
            }
          }
        }

        // (B7-3) ATTACH NEW CALENDAR TO DATEPICKER
        days.innerHTML = "";
        days.appendChild(table);
      },

      // (C) CHOOSE A DATE
      // el : HTML reference to selected date cell
      pick: function (el) {
        // (C1) GET ALL COMPONENTS
        var parent = el.parentElement;
        while (!parent.classList.contains("picker")) {
          parent = parent.parentElement;
        }

        // (C2) GET FULL SELECTED YEAR MONTH DAY
        var year = parent.getElementsByClassName("picker-y")[0].value,
          month = parent.getElementsByClassName("picker-m")[0].value,
          day = el.innerHTML;

        // YYYY-MM-DD FORMAT - CHANGE FORMAT HERE IF YOU WANT !
        if (parseInt(month) < 10) {
          month = "0" + month;
        }
        if (parseInt(day) < 10) {
          day = "0" + day;
        }
        var fullDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

        // (C3) UPDATE SELECTED DATE
        document.getElementById(parent.dataset.target).value = fullDate;

        // (C4) POPUP ONLY - CLOSE THE POPUP
        if (parent.dataset.popup == "1") {
          document
            .getElementById("picker-" + parent.dataset.dpid)
            .classList.remove("show");
        }
      },
    };
  </script>
</html>
```

Since I don't want the inline date picker and only want the pop-up date picker, I thought all I would need to do is remove this section:

```
    <!-- (B1) INLINE DATE PICKER -->
    <input type="text" id="input-inline" placeholder="Inline"/>
    <div id="pick-inline"></div>
```

but when I do that the pop-up stops working as well.  What do I need to change to remove the inline but just keep the pop-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commented the template code for the inline date picker, but you have not commented the script for inline date picker.

**Comment out** the below code to make your solution working.

```
// Comment this code block in script
picker.attach({
    target: "input-inline",
    container: "pick-inline",
});
```

**Why this was throwing error?**

The datepicker was trying to find a target from dom having id `input-inline`. Since you have commented it out, it will not be available. Thats why it was stoping the execution of javascript. The code got broken there and the lines below that is not executed. This is why your popup date picker was also not working.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // (C1) INLINE DATE PICKER
    // picker.attach({
    //     target: "input-inline",
    //     container: "pick-inline",
    // });

    // (C2) POPUP DATE PICKER
    picker.attach({
        target: "input-pop",
    });
});
var picker = {
    // (A) ATTACH DATEPICKER TO TARGET
    // target : datepicker will populate this field
    // container : datepicker will be generated in this container
    // startmon : start on Monday (default false)
    // disableday : array of days to disable, e.g. [2,7] to disable Tue and Sun
    attach: function (opt) {
        // (A1) CREATE NEW DATEPICKER
        var dp = document.createElement("div");
        dp.dataset.target = opt.target;
        dp.dataset.startmon = opt.startmon ? "1" : "0";
        dp.classList.add("picker");
        if (opt.disableday) {
            dp.dataset.disableday = JSON.stringify(opt.disableday);
        }

        // (A2) DEFAULT TO CURRENT MONTH + YEAR - NOTE: UTC+0!
        var today = new Date(),
            thisMonth = today.getUTCMonth(), // Note: Jan is 0
            thisYear = today.getUTCFullYear(),
            months = [
                "Jan",
                "Feb",
                "Mar",
                "Apr",
                "May",
                "Jun",
                "Jul",
                "Aug",
                "Sep",
                "Oct",
                "Nov",
                "Dec",
            ];

        // (A3) MONTH SELECT
        var select = document.createElement("select"),
            option = null;
        select.classList.add("picker-m");
        for (var mth in months) {
            option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = parseInt(mth) + 1;
            option.text = months[mth];
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
        select.selectedIndex = thisMonth;
        select.addEventListener("change", function () {
            picker.draw(this);
        });
        dp.appendChild(select);

        // (A4) YEAR SELECT
        var yRange = 10; // Year range to show, I.E. from thisYear-yRange to thisYear+yRange
        select = document.createElement("select");
        select.classList.add("picker-y");
        for (var y = thisYear - yRange; y < thisYear + yRange; y++) {
            option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = y;
            option.text = y;
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
        select.selectedIndex = yRange;
        select.addEventListener("change", function () {
            picker.draw(this);
        });
        dp.appendChild(select);

        // (A5) DAY SELECT
        var days = document.createElement("div");
        days.classList.add("picker-d");
        dp.appendChild(days);

        // (A6) ATTACH DATE PICKER TO TARGET CONTAINER + DRAW THE DATES
        picker.draw(select);

        // (A6-I) INLINE DATE PICKER
        if (opt.container) {
            document.getElementById(opt.container).appendChild(dp);
        }

        // (A6-P) POPUP DATE PICKER
        else {
            // (A6-P-1) MARK THIS AS A "POPUP"
            var uniqueID = 0;
            while (document.getElementById("picker-" + uniqueID) != null) {
                uniqueID = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 2)) + 1;
            }
            dp.dataset.popup = "1";
            dp.dataset.dpid = uniqueID;

            // (A6-P-2) CREATE WRAPPER
            var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
            wrapper.id = "picker-" + uniqueID;
            wrapper.classList.add("picker-wrap");
            wrapper.appendChild(dp);

            // (A6-P-3) ATTACH ONCLICK TO SHOW/HIDE DATEPICKER
            var target = document.getElementById(opt.target);
            target.dataset.dp = uniqueID;
            target.readOnly = true; // Prevent onscreen keyboar on mobile devices
            target.onfocus = function () {
                document
                    .getElementById("picker-" + this.dataset.dp)
                    .classList.add("show");
            };
            wrapper.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
                if (evt.target.classList.contains("picker-wrap")) {
                    this.classList.remove("show");
                }
            });

            // (A6-P-4) ATTACH POPUP DATEPICKER TO BODY
            document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
        }
    },

    // (B) DRAW THE DAYS IN MONTH
    // el : HTML reference to either year or month selector
    draw: function (el) {
        // (B1) GET DATE PICKER COMPONENTS
        var parent = el.parentElement,
            year = parent.getElementsByClassName("picker-y")[0].value,
            month = parent.getElementsByClassName("picker-m")[0].value,
            days = parent.getElementsByClassName("picker-d")[0];

        // (B2) DATE RANGE CALCULATION - NOTE: UTC+0!
        var daysInMonth = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, 0)).getUTCDate(),
            startDay = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, 1)).getUTCDay(), // Note: Sun = 0
            endDay = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, daysInMonth)).getUTCDay(),
            startDay = startDay == 0 ? 7 : startDay,
            endDay = endDay == 0 ? 7 : endDay;

        // (B3) GENERATE DATE SQUARES (IN ARRAY FIRST)
        var squares = [],
            disableday = null;
        if (parent.dataset.disableday) {
            disableday = JSON.parse(parent.dataset.disableday);
        }

        // (B4) EMPTY SQUARES BEFORE FIRST DAY OF MONTH
        if (parent.dataset.startmon == "1" && startDay != 1) {
            for (var i = 1; i < startDay; i++) {
                squares.push("B");
            }
        }
        if (parent.dataset.startmon == "0" && startDay != 7) {
            for (var i = 0; i < startDay; i++) {
                squares.push("B");
            }
        }

        // (B5) DAYS OF MONTH
        // (B5-1) ALL DAYS ENABLED, JUST ADD
        if (disableday == null) {
            for (var i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
                squares.push([i, false]);
            }
        }

        // (B5-2) SOME DAYS DISABLED
        else {
            var thisday = startDay;
            for (var i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
                // CHECK IF DAY IS DISABLED
                var disabled = disableday.includes(thisday);
                // DAY OF MONTH, DISABLED
                squares.push([i, disabled]);
                // NEXT DAY
                thisday++;
                if (thisday == 8) {
                    thisday = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        // (B6) EMPTY SQUARES AFTER LAST DAY OF MONTH
        if (parent.dataset.startmon == "1" && endDay != 7) {
            for (var i = endDay; i < 7; i++) {
                squares.push("B");
            }
        }
        if (parent.dataset.startmon == "0" && endDay != 6) {
            for (var i = endDay; i < (endDay == 7 ? 13 : 6); i++) {
                squares.push("B");
            }
        }

        // (B7) DRAW HTML
        var daynames = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat"];
        if (parent.dataset.startmon == "1") {
            daynames.push("Sun");
        } else {
            daynames.unshift("Sun");
        }

        // (B7-1) HTML DATE HEADER
        var table = document.createElement("table"),
            row = table.insertRow(),
            cell = null;
        row.classList.add("picker-d-h");
        for (let d of daynames) {
            cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.innerHTML = d;
        }

        // (B7-2) HTML DATE CELLS
        var total = squares.length,
            row = table.insertRow(),
            today = new Date(),
            todayDate = null;
        if (
            today.getUTCMonth() + 1 == month &&
            today.getUTCFullYear() == year
        ) {
            todayDate = today.getUTCDate();
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            if (i != total && i % 7 == 0) {
                row = table.insertRow();
            }
            cell = row.insertCell();
            if (squares[i] == "B") {
                cell.classList.add("picker-d-b");
            } else {
                cell.innerHTML = squares[i][0];
                // NOT ALLOWED TO CHOOSE THIS DAY
                if (squares[i][1]) {
                    cell.classList.add("picker-d-dd");
                }
                // ALLOWED TO CHOOSE THIS DAY
                else {
                    if (i == todayDate) {
                        cell.classList.add("picker-d-td");
                    }
                    cell.classList.add("picker-d-d");
                    cell.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        picker.pick(this);
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        // (B7-3) ATTACH NEW CALENDAR TO DATEPICKER
        days.innerHTML = "";
        days.appendChild(table);
    },

    // (C) CHOOSE A DATE
    // el : HTML reference to selected date cell
    pick: function (el) {
        // (C1) GET ALL COMPONENTS
        var parent = el.parentElement;
        while (!parent.classList.contains("picker")) {
            parent = parent.parentElement;
        }

        // (C2) GET FULL SELECTED YEAR MONTH DAY
        var year = parent.getElementsByClassName("picker-y")[0].value,
            month = parent.getElementsByClassName("picker-m")[0].value,
            day = el.innerHTML;

        // YYYY-MM-DD FORMAT - CHANGE FORMAT HERE IF YOU WANT !
        if (parseInt(month) < 10) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        if (parseInt(day) < 10) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        var fullDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

        // (C3) UPDATE SELECTED DATE
        document.getElementById(parent.dataset.target).value = fullDate;

        // (C4) POPUP ONLY - CLOSE THE POPUP
        if (parent.dataset.popup == "1") {
            document
                .getElementById("picker-" + parent.dataset.dpid)
                .classList.remove("show");
        }
    },
};
```

```css
/* (A) POPUP */
.picker-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.picker-wrap.show {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.picker-wrap .picker {
    margin: 50vh auto 0 auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* (B) CONTAINER */
.picker {
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #444444;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* (C) MONTH + YEAR */
.picker-m,
.picker-y {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* (D) DAY */
.picker-d table {
    color: #fff;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.picker-d table td {
    width: 14.28%;
    /* 7 EQUAL COLUMNS */
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* HEADER CELLS */
.picker-d-h td {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* BLANK DATES */
.picker-d-b {
    background: #4e4e4e;
}

/* TODAY */
.picker-d-td {
    background: #d84f4f;
}

/* PICKABLE DATES */
.picker-d-d:hover {
    cursor: pointer;

    /* UNPICKABLE DATES */
    .picker-d-dd {
        color: #888;
        background: #4e4e4e;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- (B) THE HTML  -->
<!-- (B1) INLINE DATE PICKER -->
<!-- <input type="text" id="input-inline" placeholder="Inline" />
<div id="pick-inline"></div> -->

<!-- (B2) POPUP DATE PICKER -->
<input type="text" id="input-pop" placeholder="Popup" />
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thank you for your clear and concise answer.  I was able to use it to find the problems and correct the code.